# My server returns a list of line numbers and I want to add custom styling to those lines , how to do that in Angular 9?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

My Code for `app.component.ts`

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  fileContent: string = '';

  public onChange(fileList: FileList): void {
    let file = fileList[0];
    let fileReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    let self = this;
    fileReader.onloadend = function(x) {
      self.fileContent = fileReader.result;
    }
    fileReader.readAsText(file);
  }
}
```

My Code for `app.component.html`

```js
<input type="file" (change)="onChange($event.target.files)">

<div>
  <h3>File Content</h3>
  <pre> {{fileContent}} </pre>
</div>
```

Now my `pre` tag shows the file content, but it doesn't shows the line numbers. My Server API will send back a result to me like `[2,12,4]` and I would like to color this line red, how can I do that ?

E.g. Let's say I have a file

```
{ 
    "person":{
        "name":"some_name",
        "age":20
    }
}
```

Now I want line 2 and line 3 to color red
`Line 2->"person:{"`
`Line 3 -> "name":"some_name",`

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

To change it to red color you would do that:

My Code for app.component.html:

```
<input type="file" (change)="onChange($event.target.files)">

<div>
  <h3>File Content</h3>
  <pre id="textColor"> {{fileContent}} </pre>
</div>
```

And in the app.component.css add the following:

```
#textColor{
color=red;
}
```

(but it doesn't shows the line numbers) I don't understand what you mean by this

Comment: I want some specific lines to color red, not the whole document

Comment: Maybe you need to give a better example in your post!, The example I gave you will change everything in the pre tag to red

Comment: I have added an example

Comment: will your data always be like that? { 
    "person":{
        "name":"some_name",
        "age":20
    }
} If it is than it is easy, but if not I think you would have to process the string.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks